# overall AUC of two different AUC's

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, prediction, auc

I have a dataset where I divide it (based on nodule longest diameter) into two subsets  of cancer features.
I have got the prediction accuracy for each subset and the AUC's. I would like to combine the two AUC's of each subset into one AUC. 
Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the scores of two randomly-chosen individuals with response values $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ the probabilistic interpretation of the AUC is that it's an estimate of $P(S_1 > S_2 \mid Y_1 > Y_2)$.  If we were to condition this probability on the subset to which an observation belongs and then take an expectation we would just get back the original probability (this is sometimes called taking an *iterated expectation*), so simply taking a weighted average of the two AUC values based on sample size should be perfectly reasonable approach.  Is there a reason why you can't just calculate the overall AUC directly?